# Docker - Deamon Context is not pointing to local directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am on MAC and have docker desktop running. My dockerfile looks something like this -

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk:8
ARG buildNumber
COPY build/libs/my-jar${buildNumber}.jar my-jar.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java  -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -noverify ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar my-jar.jar
```

When I try to build an image `docker build -t my-image:0.1 .`, the COPY stage fails. What I mean is even though my current directory is `/usr/me/projects/my-proj` the COPY stage fails with an error message -

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder436046791/build/libs/my-jar.jar: no such file or directory
```

I would assume that the path I provided was for current dir. But docker is not building on my local machine, but building it remotely some place.

Output of docker context is -

```
docker context list          
NAME                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT               KUBERNETES ENDPOINT                                          ORCHESTRATOR
default *           Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock   https://me-something.hcp.centralus.azmk8s.io:443 (default)   swarm
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What is in `./build/libs`, starting from the same directory your `Dockerfile` is in?

Comment: ```build/libs/``` is the directory that has my built artifacts, in this case, my jar. The build directory is in the same dir as my Dockerfile

Comment: Figured it out, minikube was acting as my docker deamon. I had to unset it.